# How to convert pounds to kilograms using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that allows the user to enter a weight, in either pounds or kilograms.

I'd like to store all of the data in kilograms, and using jQuery, would like the form to convert the weight_value to kilograms and change the weight_units option to "kg".

> 1 pound = 0.45359237 kilograms

The function should round the weight_value to the nearest kilogram (no decimals).

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

```
<label> Weight:</label>
<input type="text" id="weight_value" />
<select id="weight_unit" />
   <option value="lbs">lbs</option>
   <option value="kg">kg</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you're storing this value server-side, it would be better to do this calculation in PHP before putting it into the database. Doing it the way you're suggesting in jQuery will lead to a few UX problems, such as the value changing unexpectedly and people perhaps not realising the unit has changed when they edit the field.

Comment: Is it what would user appreciate? You can transparently convert the units using PHP (or whatever backend you are using) based on the weight_unit value.

Comment: @Tomalak you feeling OK? Every post of yours today has been very vitriolic.

Comment: @Rory: Every post of mine ever has been vitriolic ;) No, but jokes aside, my patience for this low-quality off-topic help-me-with-my-codez stuff is at an all-time low, I admit.

Comment: I'm with Tomalak -- helping with coding is what we are all about, but this sort of problem is so basic it boggles the mind that it would even need to be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
var kg = 0.45359237

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#weight_unit").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "kg") {
            $("#weight_value").val(Math.round( $("#weight_value").val()*kg))
        } else {
            $("#weight_value").val(Math.round( $("#weight_value").val()/kg))
        }
    });
});
```

See it live on: http://jsfiddle.net/zeByX/

[EDIT] With the `Math.floor()`, you can get some weird results by switching from kg to pounds (try with 12 pounds and switch).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking to have the converted value populate into the same weight_value field, when the focus is taken off the element, I guess.  Also, have the result rounded to the nearest kilogram.

Comment: Then, you can use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`. I don't understand when you want to trigger the calculation >> focus of which element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function KtoLbs(pK) {
    var nearExact = pK/0.45359237;
    var lbs = Math.floor(nearExact);

    return {
        pounds: lbs,

    };
}

var imperial = KtoLbs(10);
alert("10 kg = " + imperial.pounds + " lbs " );
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mVNDk/

```
$('#weight_unit').change(function(){
    var v = $('input').val();
    if($('#weight_unit').val() == 'lbs') {
        $('input').val(v * 0.4535923);
    } else {
        $('input').val(v / 0.4535923);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $("#weight_value").keyup(function(){
            var weight = parseFloat($("#weight_value").val());
            if($("#weight_unit").val()=='lbs'){
                //lbs value;
                weight = (weight/0.45359237); 
            }else{
            }
            $("#weight_value_kg").val(Math.round(weight*100)/100);

        });

    });
```

---

```
<label> Weight:</label>
<input type="text" id="weight_value" />
<select id="weight_unit" />
    <option value="lbs">lbs</option>
    <option value="kg">kg</option>
</select>
<label> value:in kg</label>
<input type="text" id="weight_value_kg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here's some code

```
$("#weight_unit").change(function() {
    var result = 0;
    if($(this).val() == "kg") {
        result = Math.round($("#weight_value").val() * 0.45359237);
        alert( result + " kg");
    }
    else {
        result = Math.round($("#weight_value").val() / 0.45359237);
        alert( result + " lbs");
    }
});
```

you should replace the `alert()` functions for something you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/HURQQ/) buddy.

```
<label for='weight'>Weight</label>
<input type='text' id='weight' />
<select id='units'>
    <option value='p'>Pound</option>
    <option value='k'>Killogram</optoin>
</select>
<input type='text' id='result' />
```

with this script:

```
var weight = $('#weight'),
    units = $('#units'),
    result = $('#result');
// 1 pound = 0.45359237 kilograms
$(function() {
    units.change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'p') {
            // Weight is in Pound  
            result.val(weight.val() * 0.45359237);
        }
        else {
            // Wiehgt is in Killogram
            result.val(weight.val() / 0.45359237);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks; however, I'm looking to have the converted value populate into the same weight_value field, when the focus is taken off the element, I guess.